# Guidance on putting two divs, side by side, in a container (parent div)

Tags: html, css

I understand there are a lot of questions similar to this topic, but I haven't achieved anything, to no avail! Some help and guidance would be great.

@media 928px I am trying to float these two divs side by side, just above the footer. The are both inside a parent container (.vd-grid-right-col).

I have tried using float, clearing them and overflow:hidden, but none of them seem to work. Have a look, would love to hear your amazing advice.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Vivid Global Styling*/

html {} body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.wht {
  color: #fff;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}
.vd-hide {
  display: none;
}
.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}
.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}
.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}
/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 22px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}
/*Vivid Main Wrapper*/

.vd-page-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Grid*/

.vd-grid h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid p,
span {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.vd-grid h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h3 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h4 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid {
  width: 98.6%;
  margin: 13px auto;
}
.vd-grid-left-col {
  width: 77.6%;
  float: left;
}
.vd-grid-right-col {
  width: 20.8%;
  float: left;
}
.vd-grid-main-box {
  width: 93.5%;
  height: 460px;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3.2%;
}
.vd-grid-main-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.vd-grid-sub-box {
  width: 30.8%;
  height: 159px;
  background-image: url(../img/granda_hj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #000029;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.9%;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0.2%;
}
.vd-grid-xtra-box {
  width: 94%;
  height: 332px;
  background-image: url(../img/tst_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3%;
}
.vd-text-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 340px;
  left: 0px;
}
.vd-margin-top {
  margin-top: 4%;
}
.vd-margin-right {
  /*! margin-right:10px; */
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.vd-margin-left {
  /*! margin-left:10px; */
  margin-left: 0.8%;
}
.vd-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
/*Vivid Footer*/

.vd-footer {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-color: #000029;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.vd-widget-area {
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto 0px;
}
.vd-footer-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-footer-links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 30px 25px 0;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: outside none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.vd-footer-links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.vd-signup {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 305px;
  width: 26%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.vd-sub-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Payment Icons*/

.vd-payment-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #a7a7a7;
}
.vd-footer-linklist .vd-social-icon:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Social Icons';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-payment-options {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options ul {
  display: block-inline;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options li {
  display: block-inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.american-express:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.bitcoin:before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.jcb:before {
  content: "\f028";
}
.master:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
.paypal:before {
  content: "\f033";
}
.visa:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
/*Vivid Copyright*/

.vd-copyright-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*Vivid Responsive*/

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {}@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
  .vd-grid-left-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .vd-grid-xtra-box {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <title>Vivid Shop Display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='css/vivid-style.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/scroller.css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
      <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
        <div class="vd-user-settings">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-currency-selector">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-language-selector">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Shop</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li class="vd-logo-img">
            <img src="img/vivid_logo.png" />
          </li>
          <li>Lookbook</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
        <div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--Mobile Navigation-->
    <nav class="vd-hide">
      <div class="header-top clearfix">
        <a class="nav toggle-menu" href="#">
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
        </a>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="#firstSection"><img src="img/harva_logo.png"/></a></h1>
      </div>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
          <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
          <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
          <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
          <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
          <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
          <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--End Mobile Navigation-->

    <div class="vd-grid">
      <div class="vd-grid-left-col">
        <div class="vd-grid-main-box vd-margin-bottom">
          <div class="vd-text-wrap">
            <h1>Header Text</h1>
            <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
            <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-right-col vd-margin-left">
        <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box">
          <h4>Header Text</h4>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box vd-margin-top vd-margin-bottom">
          <h4>Header Text</h4>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer class="vd-footer">
    <div class="vd-widget-area">
      <div class="vd-footer-text">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">V I V I D - SHOPIFY THEME</h4>
        <div class="rte">V I V I D is a customisable theme that looks and feels fantastic. Showcase your products on the visually stunning V I V I D Grid and choose your structure then let V I V I D do the rest!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">HELP</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="" href="#">HELP | FAQ'S</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">RETURNS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">HOW TO SHOP</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">STOCKISTS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">POLICIES</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="" href="#">DELIVERY &amp; RETURNS POLICY</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">SECURITY POLICY</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">CONNECT</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon facebook" href="#" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon twitter" href="#" target="_blank">TWITTER</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon instagram" href="#" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon vimeo" href="#" target="_blank">VIMEO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-signup">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h4>
        <div class="wht">HTML Block to be added here for embedded email capture forms</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-sub-footer">
      <ul class="vd-payment-options">
        <li class="vd-payment-icon american-express"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon bitcoin"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon jcb"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon master"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon paypal"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon visa"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="vd-copyright-wrapper">
        <p class="vd-copyright">Copyright © 2017 V I V I D Themes.</p>
        <p class="vd-attribution">"Virtual Visual Merchandising"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: --> .vd-grid-right-col { width: 20.8%; float: left; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had given `.vd-grid-right-col` a width of `20.8%` and that's the bulk of your problems.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

/*Vivid Global Styling*/

html {} body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ul,
li,
span {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.wht {
  color: #fff;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
/*Vivid Page Settings*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: #000 1px solid;
}
.vd-hide {
  display: none;
}
.vd-settings-wrapper {
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.vd-user-settings {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 0 21px;
}
.vd-currency-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 12px 2px 1px 2px;
}
.vd-language-selector {
  width: 58px;
  height: 21px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px 2px 0 2px;
}
/*Vivid Main Navigation*/

.vd-nav-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  height: 78px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 22px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-nav-wrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 18px 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.vd-logo-img {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
/*Vivid Checkout Settings*/

.vd-cart-wrapper {
  width: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.vd-cart-selector {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: -11px 31px 0 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: -9px;
}
/*Vivid Main Wrapper*/

.vd-page-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Grid*/

.vd-grid h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid p,
span {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 17px;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
.vd-grid h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.vd-grid h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h3 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid h4 {
  margin: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
.vd-grid {
  width: 98.6%;
  margin: 13px auto;
}
.vd-grid-left-col {
  width: 77.6%;
  float: left;
}
.vd-grid-right-col {
  width: 20.8%;
  float: left;
}
.vd-grid-main-box {
  width: 93.5%;
  height: 460px;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3.2%;
}
.vd-grid-main-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
.vd-grid-sub-box {
  width: 30.8%;
  height: 159px;
  background-image: url(../img/granda_hj.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: #000029;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.9%;
  margin: 0 0 1% 0.2%;
}
.vd-grid-xtra-box {
  width: 94%;
  height: 332px;
  background-image: url(../img/tst_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: #000029;
  padding: 3%;
}
.vd-text-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 340px;
  left: 0px;
}
.vd-margin-top {
  margin-top: 4%;
}
.vd-margin-right {
  /*! margin-right:10px; */
  margin-right: 1%;
}
.vd-margin-left {
  /*! margin-left:10px; */
  margin-left: 0.8%;
}
.vd-margin-bottom {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
/*Vivid Footer*/

.vd-footer {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  padding-bottom: 55px;
  background-color: #000029;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), -moz-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
  transition: opacity 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94), transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
.vd-widget-area {
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
  border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto 0px;
}
.vd-footer-text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 26%;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-footer-links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 30px 25px 0;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-links ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: outside none;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.vd-footer-links li {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.vd-footer-links a:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
}
.vd-footer-title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
.vd-signup {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 305px;
  width: 26%;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.vd-sub-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding-top: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
  max-width: 1260px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Vivid Payment Icons*/

.vd-payment-icon {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.2;
  color: #a7a7a7;
}
.vd-footer-linklist .vd-social-icon:before {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Social Icons';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.vd-payment-options {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  list-style: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options ul {
  display: block-inline;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.vd-payment-options li {
  display: block-inline;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-type: outside none;
}
.american-express:before {
  content: "\f001";
}
.bitcoin:before {
  content: "\f006";
}
.jcb:before {
  content: "\f028";
}
.master:before {
  content: "\f02d";
}
.paypal:before {
  content: "\f033";
}
.visa:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
/*Vivid Copyright*/

.vd-copyright-wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  -moz-font-smoothing: none;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*Vivid Responsive*/

@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {}@media screen and (max-width: 928px) {
  .vd-grid-left-col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col > div {
    width: 49%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .vd-grid-right-col > div:first-child {
    margin-right:2%;
  }
  .vd-grid-xtra-box {
    float: left;
  }
  .vd-footer{
    margin-top: 20px;  
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
  <title>Vivid Shop Display</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href='css/vivid-style.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/scroller.css'>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="vd-navigation-wrapper">
      <div class="vd-settings-wrapper">
        <div class="vd-user-settings">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-currency-selector">
        </div>
        <div class="vd-language-selector">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-nav-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li>Shop</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li class="vd-logo-img">
            <img src="img/vivid_logo.png" />
          </li>
          <li>Lookbook</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-cart-wrapper">
        <div class="vd-cart-selector"></div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--Mobile Navigation-->
    <nav class="vd-hide">
      <div class="header-top clearfix">
        <a class="nav toggle-menu" href="#">
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
          <i></i>
        </a>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="#firstSection"><img src="img/harva_logo.png"/></a></h1>
      </div>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstSection">
          <a href="#firstSection" title="First Section">First Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondSection">
          <a href="#secondSection" title="Second Section">Second Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="thirdSection">
          <a href="#thirdSection" title="Second Section">Third Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fourthSection">
          <a href="#fourthSection" title="Fourth Section">Fourth Section</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection">
          <a href="#fifthSection" title="First Slide">First Slide</a>
        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="fifthSection/1">
          <a href="#fifthSection/1" title="Second Slide">Second Slide</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--End Mobile Navigation-->

    <div class="vd-grid">
      <div class="vd-grid-left-col">
        <div class="vd-grid-main-box vd-margin-bottom">
          <div class="vd-text-wrap">
            <h1>Header Text</h1>
            <h2>Secondary Title</h2>
            <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box vd-margin-right vd-margin-left">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-sub-box">
          <h3>Header Text</h3>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-grid-right-col vd-margin-left">
        <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box">
          <h4>Header Text</h4>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vd-grid-xtra-box vd-margin-top vd-margin-bottom">
          <h4>Header Text</h4>
          <p>Featured Text Here over two lines if needed place here.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer class="vd-footer">
    <div class="vd-widget-area">
      <div class="vd-footer-text">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">V I V I D - SHOPIFY THEME</h4>
        <div class="rte">V I V I D is a customisable theme that looks and feels fantastic. Showcase your products on the visually stunning V I V I D Grid and choose your structure then let V I V I D do the rest!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">HELP</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="" href="#">HELP | FAQ'S</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">RETURNS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">HOW TO SHOP</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">CONTACT US</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">STOCKISTS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">POLICIES</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="" href="#">DELIVERY &amp; RETURNS POLICY</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">TERMS &amp; CONDITIONS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="" href="#">SECURITY POLICY</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-footer-links">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">CONNECT</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon facebook" href="#" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon twitter" href="#" target="_blank">TWITTER</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon instagram" href="#" target="_blank">INSTAGRAM</a>
          </li>
          <li><a class="vd-social-icon vimeo" href="#" target="_blank">VIMEO</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="vd-signup">
        <h4 class="vd-footer-title">SIGN UP TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h4>
        <div class="wht">HTML Block to be added here for embedded email capture forms</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vd-sub-footer">
      <ul class="vd-payment-options">
        <li class="vd-payment-icon american-express"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon bitcoin"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon jcb"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon master"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon paypal"></li>
        <li class="vd-payment-icon visa"></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="vd-copyright-wrapper">
        <p class="vd-copyright">Copyright © 2017 V I V I D Themes.</p>
        <p class="vd-attribution">"Virtual Visual Merchandising"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: .vd-grid-right-col { width: 20.8%; float: left; }
 then : vd-grid-xtra-box have fixed heights and %-set width.

Comment: Thank you all for your time to reply. I don't quite understand as I am trying to get the two div's in the container, side by side. If I adjust the width or heights everything will still be the same

Comment: Even if I adjust the width, the parent div will just expand with the two divs inside them. I am looking to align the two divs, side by side, in the container.

Comment: What selector is used for this? I am trying float but it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry if it was misread, I am looking to achieve this @media 928px, so the two divs will just be above the footer.

Comment: I either don't understand you or I already did this and you don't understand my solution.

Comment: Oh dear, sorry I completely missed you.